# Yum not able to update to a fixed version suggested by trivy security scan inside AWS lambda image

Tags: amazon-web-services, yum

I'm building a very basic Dockerfile for a python-based AWS lambda,

Dockerfile (`docker build -f Dockerfile -t test-img:0.0.1 .`):

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9
RUN yum update -y && yum install libgomp -y && yum clean all
```

A trivy scan is showing vulnerabilities from `openldap`. I attempt to `yum update openldap` and it can't find the fixed version suggested by the trivy scan, `2.4.44-25.amzn2.0.5`, it returns `No package openldap-2.4.44-25.amzn2.0.5 available.`

`trivy --cache-dir .trivycache/ image --ignore-unfixed --no-progress --exit-code 1  --input test-lambda.tar`

Does anyone know how I can update to the suggested version?

[image]

Security notes here: https://alas.aws.amazon.com/AL2/ALAS-2023-2033.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue but with a Java-based Amazon image.

I just updated the base image to a version that did not have any vulnerabilities, you may be able to do something similar. I often find that upgrading the base image is the simplest way to go in order to squash image-based dependencies, it at least narrows down the offenders.

For example, I went from

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17
```

to:

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17.0.7-al2023
```

And this fixed Trivy scanner reporting problems with `openldap`

Answer (score 1):

Until a new image is published, you can also force the update of the base image within your Dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10
RUN yum update -y openldap glib2 libssh2
```

The above cleared the openldap finding in the scans by AWS ECR.